# Creating a table in MySQL vs Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

In MySQL my table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `cat_activo` (  
    `id_activo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tarjeta` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `id_area` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `id_clase` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `fecha_ingreso` date NOT NULL, 
    `fecha_retiro` date NOT NULL,
    `fecha_real_retiro` date NOT NULL,
    `nombre` varchar(300) NOT NULL, 
    `serie` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `placa` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `caracter` text NOT NULL,
    `valor_original` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `valor_residual` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `plazo_depreciar` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valor_depreciar` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `porcentaje` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `depreciacion_acumulada` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cuota_anual` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `saldo_depreciar` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cuota_mensual` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cuota_mensual` double(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ruta_archivo` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    `estado` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_activo`,`tarjeta`),
    KEY `fkArea` (`id_area`),
    KEY `fkClase` (`id_clase`)
);
```

In Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE cat_activo(
    id_activo number(10) NOT NULL,
    tarjeta number(10) NOT NULL,
    id_area number(10) NOT NULL,
    id_clase number(10) NOT NULL,
    fecha_ingreso date NOT NULL,
    fecha_retiro date NOT NULL,
    fecha_real_retiro date NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar2(300) NOT NULL,
    serie varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
    placa varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    caracteristicas long NOT NULL,
    valor_original number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    valor_residual number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    plazo_depreciar number(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    valor_depreciar number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    porcentaje number(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    depreciacion_acumulada number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    cuota_anual number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    saldo_depreciar number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    cuota_mensual number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    ruta_archivo varchar2(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    estado number(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_activo,tarjeta),
    KEY fkArea (id_area),
    KEY fkClase (id_clase)
);
```

The MySQL version works, but in Oracle I get the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578 ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057 3.   tarjeta number(10) NOT NULL,4.   id_area number(10) NOT NULL,5.   id_clase number(10) NOT NULL,6.   fecha_ingreso date NOT NULL, 7.   fecha_retiro date NOT NULL,

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

NOTES:

- The `NOT NULL` constraint has to be *after* the `DEFAULT` clause.  Sort of documented here in the train track syntax diagram. (The `NOT NULL` is actually a constraint definition, so has to be at the end of the column definition.

[image: column definition train track diagram]

- The `KEY` syntax is not valid in Oracle. Use a `CREATE INDEX` statement instead.
- The `LONG` datatype is deprecated since 8.0. Unless we have a specific reason to use that datatype, I'd opt for newer `CLOB` datatype.
- I'd opt to use a specific name for the PRIMARY KEY constraint rather than a system assigned name; but that's not a syntax problem.

---

Something like this should work in Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE cat_activo
( id_activo              NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL
, tarjeta                NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL
, id_area                NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL
, id_clase               NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL
, fecha_ingreso          DATE           NOT NULL
, fecha_retiro           DATE           NOT NULL
, fecha_real_retiro      DATE           NOT NULL
, nombre                 VARCHAR2(300)  NOT NULL
, serie                  VARCHAR2(100)  NOT NULL
, placa                  VARCHAR2(30)   NOT NULL
, caracteristicas      CLOB             NOT NULL
, valor_original         NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL
, valor_residual         NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL 
, plazo_depreciar        NUMBER(10)     DEFAULT 0      NOT NULL 
, valor_depreciar        NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL  
, porcentaje             NUMBER(10,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL  
, depreciacion_acumulada NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL  
, cuota_anual            NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL  
, saldo_depreciar        NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL  
, cuota_mensual          NUMBER(18,2)   DEFAULT 0.00   NOT NULL  
, ruta_archivo           VARCHAR2(200)  DEFAULT ' '    NOT NULL
, estado                 NUMBER(4)      DEFAULT 0      NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (id_activo,tarjeta)
);
CREATE INDEX cat_activo_fkArea ON cat_activo (id_area) ;
CREATE INDEX cat_activo_fkClase ON cat_activo (id_clase) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You first problem is with this syntax:

```
valor_residual number(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
```

In Oracle, the `DEFAULT` option must be placed after the `DEFAULT`, so this should be:

```
valor_original number(18,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL
```

---

The second problem is with this syntax:

```
KEY fkArea (id_area)
```

As far as concerned there is no syntax in Oracle to create a non-unique index within a `create table` statement. If you want a `unique` index, this can be done by adding a constraint when the table is created:

```
id_area number(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fkArea UNIQUE USING INDEX
```

If you do want a non-unique index, you need to use a separate `create index` statement:

```
create index fkArea on cat_activo(id_area);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f10366694d2ec3cae639c45832a379b2)**:

```
CREATE TABLE cat_activo(  
    id_activo number(10) NOT NULL,  
    tarjeta number(10) NOT NULL, 
    id_area number(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fkArea UNIQUE USING INDEX,  -- unique index
    id_clase number(10) NOT NULL,  
    fecha_ingreso date NOT NULL,  
    fecha_retiro date NOT NULL,  
    fecha_real_retiro date NOT NULL,  
    nombre varchar2(300) NOT NULL,  
    serie varchar2(100) NOT NULL,  
    placa varchar2(30) NOT NULL, 
    caracteristicas long NOT NULL,  
    valor_original number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    valor_residual number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    plazo_depreciar number(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    valor_depreciar number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    porcentaje number(10,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,  
    depreciacion_acumulada number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,  
    cuota_anual number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    saldo_depreciar number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    cuota_mensual number(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    ruta_archivo varchar2(200) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
    estado number(4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_activo,tarjeta)
);


-- non-unique index
create index fkClase on cat_activo(id_clase);
```